# how to print a string with seperation of certain letters with spaces between them in python3?

Tags: string, python-3.x, spacing

I want to print the output as :

```
543 
543 543 
543 543 543 
543 543 543 543 
543 543 543 543 543 
543 543 543 543 543 543 
543 543 543 543 543 543 543
```

but i am getting :

```
5 4 3
5 4 3 5 4 3
5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3
5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3
5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3
5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3 5 4 3
```

my code is:

```
n,m = input().split(" ")
m = int(m)
i = 0
while(i<m):
    x = i*n
    print(*x)
    i += 1
```

anybody please explain me how can i print a group of characters with spaces in between them instead of spacing between each and every character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the space somewhere. I recommend adding it to `n`. The `*` operator is also unnecessary (it's what is adding all the unnecessary spaces, attempting to "unpack" a string). Finally, there's not much point starting the loop at `0` so I've change the loop boundaries too:

```
n,m = input().split(" ")
m = int(m)
n = n+" "
i = 1
while(i<=m):
    x = i*n
    print(x)
    i += 1
```

Input:

```
543 6
```

Output:

```
543 
543 543 
543 543 543 
543 543 543 543 
543 543 543 543 543 
543 543 543 543 543 543
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one line solution:

```
>>> n,m = input().split()
543 6
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join([n] * i) for i in range(1, int(m) + 1)))
543
543 543
543 543 543
543 543 543 543
543 543 543 543 543
543 543 543 543 543 543
```